# Multiple IIS server share same domain and port?

Tags: networking, dns, iis

I have the following network/server setup:

[image]

Since this is for a startup I'm working on with a friend using the resources we have, we use a DD-WRT router to redirect port 80 requests to a specific server, and we're using a free no-ip domain for now, so no subdomains. Now, the problem is:

I need to add a second server which must host .NET apps and I need it as a separate machine. Thing is, port 80 requests go to the first server, not to the second one. I could make it use another port, but I don't want to since it is not what I'm looking for.

My idea is to create a THIRD IIS server that would host virtual directories (?) so that, /someApp goes to the first server and /anotherApp goes to the second server. This is so that I can take offline the 2nd server without affecting the first one. I wouldn't be able to access /anotherApp, but /someApp wouldn't go offline, that's why I don't want to create the virtual directory in the first server.

Let me rephrase:

Is there a way to have something like this:

```
http://mydomain.com:80/someApp -> 192.168.1.100:80/someApp
http://mydomain.com:80/anotherApp -> 192.168.1.200:80/anotherApp
```

I wonder, is this possible? and if so, how? ISAPI redirect? HTTP rewrite? would I have problems with sessions and cookies? help! :(

Any ideas are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You're looking for "reverse proxy".

Comment: Indeed, your answer helped me to find out what I needed to archieve what I wanted to do. Thanks! (also for the edit). Too bad you didn't comment as an answer because I would've gladly marked it as is :)